# Stripe: Craft Commerce_OrderModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure ....

Tags: error-message

I'm trying to accept Stripe payments and am stuck in a loop where I have optimal behavior on the dev and staging versions, but then things broke in production and got the following error message:

Craft\Commerce_OrderModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named 'firstName'

Can someone give me some direction around this? Again, it only happens in production, and obviously, we need to be able to receive payment from customers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all environments are identical? (Same templates, versions, plugins, configs, etc.)

Best way is to check your craft.log file and turn on devMode so you can get a proper dump as to what's causing your problem.